# Session seems to die on Page refresh or when the page is opened in a new tab

Tags: php, session

In my project, on successful Login, a page opens which shows the username. That works perfect. But when, I refresh the same page without logout, the session seems to get destroyed and the username disappears. Also, if I try to open the page in a new tab, it shows you need to login first  and session seems to be missing or destroyed. The code used to work well few days before when I implemented and tested it. It is today, that this problem occurred. Can't figure out what the error or the problem is. Please help. 
Here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if(1==2)
{
    $message = "Login to access the books page";    
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "window.open('register.html','_self')";
    echo "</script>";
}
else
{
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
<br>
<button  id="logout">Logout</button>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#logout").click(function(){
            <?php session_destroy(); ?>
            window.open("index.html","_self");
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing javascript with php will sometimes cause unexpected results. Php inside javascript will always run. This code is causing your session to be destroyed each time the page loads because session_destroy() is always executed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logout").click(function(){
        <?php session_destroy(); ?>
        window.open("index.html","_self");
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Recently, i discovered that the value of $_SESSION['username'] is lost on page refresh. What could be the reason for that???

Comment: session_destroy() removes all $_SESSION variables. As Gaurav Rai says, run that function somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` You are destroying session, so when page loads there is no session. Redirect user to some page with `session_destroy` code, when you want user to logout.